# slicing two lists to have same size using for loop in python

Tags: python, numpy

Hello I want to create two new lists from existing lists using for loop.I know by slicing the lists I can get that result but I have a big list with more than a 1000 entries so slicing by counting the index is not very reliable.
I am learning python so there may be other ways I am not aware of so would appreciate if anyone can solve my problem.

So I have two lists say :

```
 a=np.linspace(1,10,30)
 b=np.linspcae(0,6,30)

 a
array([  1.        ,   1.31034483,   1.62068966,   1.93103448,
         2.24137931,   2.55172414,   2.86206897,   3.17241379,
         3.48275862,   3.79310345,   4.10344828,   4.4137931 ,
         4.72413793,   5.03448276,   5.34482759,   5.65517241,
         5.96551724,   6.27586207,   6.5862069 ,   6.89655172,
         7.20689655,   7.51724138,   7.82758621,   8.13793103,
         8.44827586,   8.75862069,   9.06896552,   9.37931034,
         9.68965517,  10.        ])


 b
array([ 0.        ,  0.20689655,  0.4137931 ,  0.62068966,  0.82758621,
        1.03448276,  1.24137931,  1.44827586,  1.65517241,  1.86206897,
        2.06896552,  2.27586207,  2.48275862,  2.68965517,  2.89655172,
        3.10344828,  3.31034483,  3.51724138,  3.72413793,  3.93103448,
        4.13793103,  4.34482759,  4.55172414,  4.75862069,  4.96551724,
        5.17241379,  5.37931034,  5.5862069 ,  5.79310345,  6.        ])
```

so my code is:

```
for i in a:
   if i >2.27-1. and i<2.27+1:
      print i
```

which gives me the elements I want from a.

```
1.31034482759
1.62068965517
1.93103448276
2.24137931034
2.55172413793
2.86206896552
3.1724137931
```

But I also want the corresponding elements in b.
i.e.

```
0.20689655
0.4137931
0.62068966
0.82758621
1.03448276
1.24137931
1.44827586
```

How do I go from here to get the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to avoid for loops when working with numpy, its a lot faster and kind of the point.

```
mask = (a>1.27) & (a<3.27)
a[mask]
b[mask]
```

`(a>1.27) & (a<3.27)` just returns a boolean array where the value is `True` when the conditions are satisfied and `False` elsewhere. By assigning `a` and `b` to this array you will get the values where the index of the boolean array is `True`.

Edit:

```
list(a[(a>1.27) & (a<3.27)])
list(b[(a>1.27) & (a<3.27)])
```

If you really want a list returned. If you're doing something else in this for loop then you'll want to stick to using a for loop.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought at first too, but the OP was very clear: "Hello I want to create two new lists from existing lists using for loop."

Comment: @DSM Since the for loop does nothing else I figured, along with the OP stating they are new to python, showing them a better way may serve them in future work and that their choice of using a for loop was more ignorance of other methods rather than an inherent desire to see `for i in a` in their code.

Comment: True, but the other half the time when people say they need to use for loops, it's because it's a beginner assignment and they need to learn non-vectorized approaches to things first.  It'd be nice if that were always clear, but wishes, horses, etc.

Comment: I agree. I was not aware of any other methods. So this one clearly solves my problem for now.

Comment: Is there a way to use for statement if i want to carry out summation or some other operation in this case.

Comment: If you mean you want to sum your result array you can just use `np.sum(result_array)`. You're better off making the array you want to do something with first and then using a numpy function on that array. Check the numpy docs.